# Project reactor - Cancel Flux REST API request if other two parallel flux requests are completed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I run several REST API requests in parallel. If at least 2 requests are completed successfully all others should be terminated. How to achieve this using project reactor (Spring Webflux) and Flux?

Comment: Could you be more elaborate ??  Do you want to cancel the clients you are calling ?? not very clear from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like *[Flux#take(long n)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#take-long-)*

You could subscribe your publishers eagerly, emit only *n* elements and cancel the rest.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
List<Publisher<YourType>> publishers = ...;

Flux.merge(publishers)
    .take(2)
    .......
    .......
    .subscribe(...) or return the publisher to Webflux (if you are using it)
```